# Body switch justification

Tags: science-based, psychology, brain

The scenario is simple: A man switches body with another. Social implications are not the issue here, but the "collateral effects" of body switching.

The Ghost Brigades is a book that touches in this matter, but is different because it's a "baby" getting into someone's mind.

**How the body switching happens**: it happens almost with a blink of an eye with a telephatic power of "body-spirit switching" (this is my own world lore). Only who has training in telephatic power has the ability to change bodies because the old brain will need to send/upload information through outer dimension.

**How could I justify the following result?**

- Long-term memories presents in the native brain will mostly remain.
- Short-term memories will be lost almost immediately.
- Movement skills will be "relearned" quickly.
- Genetic-based behavior will be preserved (or else, this would involve a body transformation, I guess. It would be a whole new discussion.)
- Certain aspects of the native personality would be preserved at the beginning, but gradually being lost as the "new mind" reshapes the brain. (At the beginning, the "new guest" will even have the impression that the native  memories are his memories, but as the brain is reshaped, he will know what is his and what is not.)
- When the process is done and both brains stop the "uploading", their personalities will change because it will be as they known each other since early days. Intimancy will be very high. (just like in Pacific Rim.)
- The person will need to sleep a lot in order for the brain be reshaped. That's when the uploading begins.

(Sorry for any english grammar error, I'm not native english speaker)

Comment: You’re asking us to ignore differences in brain structure while asking about changes in neural activity due to a fictional transfer process we know nothing about??

Comment: Perhaps instead of asking what would happen (I guess it depends), you should perhaps consider asking how you can justify your desired result

Comment: Yeah, I will edit to ask about how to justify a desired result. Thank you.

Comment: Body switch has no scientific basis, so I don't believe that a science based answer is possible. Effects would be whatever you want them to be.

Comment: I'd ask that the "reality-check" tag is removed as my understanding of it's use is that this is inappropriate here (when used to science-based and the base concept - body swap here - is not possible).  See [this Meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-realistic-should-a-question-tagged-reality-check-be).

Comment: I will remove the tag. It's the second time someone say that it's hard to do science with this question. I'm beginning to see that is easier to make a world-based logic (Effects would be whatever my world logic is) rather than have a scientific logic. If that's the case, I would acept an answer that explains that.

Answer (score 1):

Forget memory and thinking; they'll be ridiculously lucky not to die from muscle overdrives and fall induced brain injuries before they learn to move their new body with its different skeleton, new bone density, strange muscle attachments, and unaccustomed muscle fibre density. Humans spend their whole lives learning and maintaining movement skills based on their current body and it's particular foibles. In a new body the motor control orders could, and probably would, result in broken bones and constant falls until a whole new set of movement instincts were learned.